# Murti Sthapana - why, what and when to do

Tags: puja, idols

I have seen murti sthapana puja for common festivals like Ganapati.
Do we need to do Murti Sthapana for all the Gods we have in our home-temple?
Is it like we don't need to do Sthapana for photo-frame in the temple?
If we wish to bring in new Idol in our home-temple, is there anything specific we need to do? Like sthapana or anything else?
Can someone explain me the importance, conditions and requirements of such puja?

Comment: If u want to do murti sthapana in ur home then u have to consult a priest. He will know all the rules and he can do it but how can u do it urself ? You should let the person do the job for whom it is meant.

Comment: I'm not asking whose job it is.

Comment: And i am saying its ur purohit only who can guide u on this. If u simply ask him he can tell u what to do. By asking here u will not be benefited. IMO.

Comment: I really wonder then what is the reason people question here!!! People can ask their Purohits and read literature themselves to solve the problem as per you. Thank you as if I never knew that.

Can anyone else answer the question?

Comment: For this Q u need to consult a purohit only. Just like for ailments one needs to consult a doctor. For many other Qs asking here is perfectly fine. But for few Qs asking here is not ok. Since murti sthapana is a ritual its not recommended to learn it from net and try doing it on one's own. I hope u are getting my point :)

Comment: " learn it from net and try doing it on one's own. " >> Please don't assume anything while answering.

Comment: " learn it from net and try doing it on one's own. " >> Please don't assume anything except common sense while answering. I know whom to reach. I assumed I will get answers here and can compare the answer that I get from others.

If you have links for the same reading then provide. what you said adds 0 value to answer. It is as good as not answering.

I see you have answered other questions stating references. "Is the ritual of killing an animal .." > You could have answered there too "contact your local." But you didn't cause you knew.

I hope u are getting my point. :)

Comment: I think u are not getting my point. In that answer u pointed I am not teaching how to perform a puja or a ritual that should be best if done by the priest.. i have just provided some clarifications with my limited understanding of things..no guidelines were provided there to be followed by someone..  Anyways please wait if someone can answer.