# Is it acceptable to sleep in same room as Murti (Idol)?

Tags: scripture, temple, practice, idols, vastu-shastra

Naively speaking one might expect that it would be acceptable to sleep/ live in same place as a Murti of some God or Goddess, as can occasionally be seen in some temples. For example, the question [Keeping Deities/God photos in everywhere in home](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/29789/keeping-deities-god-photos-in-everywhere-in-home) mentions that "Bed room is an optional if someone wants to see the first sight everyday" though the issue is not addressed in the answer. I have heard similar things in some sermons.

Moreover, in most houses, there is some dedicated space or room for keeping the Murtis. So, one might use this same room for some other purpose such as storage or sleeping at the same time.

---

However, on Internet I came across some websites saying that this is a harmful practice that should be avoided.

1. Pooja room Vastu tips for every Indian home - [Homify.in](https://www.homify.in/ideabooks/4905498/pooja-room-vastu-tips-for-every-indian-home)

> In small apartments, finding the space for the pooja area can pose a challenge. It’s not uncommon to find the pooja room in kitchens or bedrooms. Although, as far as possible, these areas should be avoided for the pooja room, in some cases there is no other alternative. In such instances, and only as a last resort, if the pooja mandir is in the kitchen, ensure that it is placed in the northeast corner and has two shutters doors to keep it closed when it is not in use.

> Designing the pooja space in the bedroom should be looked at as a last resort, as Vastu prescribes that no one should sleep in the pooja room. If there is no other alternative, incorporate it in the northeast corner of the bedroom.

2. How to Design Your Pooja Room According to Vastu - [UrbanCompany.com](https://www.urbancompany.com/blog/interiors/pooja-room-vastu-tips/)

> 7. Don’t use the pooja space for any other purpose, and avoid too much storage here. If you must have storage options, then place cupboards to the west or the south.

> 16. It’s not a good idea to have a mandir in the bedroom. However, if you must, then install it in the north-east area of the bedroom.

---

These websites do not give authority of any particular sage or scripture, but instead simply say that this is "as per Vastu".

**My question is:**

1. **What do scriptures say about the proper way of keeping Murti? Can one sleep in the same room or use the place for other uses?** (Preferably Vedic or Puranic source)
2. **What if a person has shortage of space - like someone living in one small room in a rented place or hostel?** Possibly, we may be living with other people in the same room in such situations. So, is it acceptable to keep some Murti or is it better to not keep any?
3. **What is the validity of the Vastu mentioned in the cited places?** Are there any Vastu-shastra treatise which state these things and how authoritative are they?

---

I found some related questions on the site, but they do not address this issue:
[Can I keep a small murti of lord hanuman in my room](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/35767/can-i-keep-a-small-murti-of-lord-hanuman-in-my-room), [Keeping Deities/God photos in everywhere in home](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/29789/keeping-deities-god-photos-in-everywhere-in-home), [What do the scriptures mention about sleeping postures and mattresses?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/33116/what-do-the-scriptures-mention-about-sleeping-postures-and-mattresses), [Murti Sthapana - why, what and when to do](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20611/murti-sthapana-why-what-and-when-to-do)

Comment: If possible, it is best to avoid it. One should have a separate space for worship and one should only go there to worship. One should not do anything else in that place. It should be kept clean and one should burn incense there everyday.

Comment: Yes. My great grandma slept in puja room during her late age. She was fully devoted to God carrying out very difficult routine. Although I do not have scriptural references about it.

Answer (score 2):

### `1. Can one sleep in the same room or use the place for other uses?`

We can't conclusively comment on a generalized rule, because so far I haven't found one.

But in the Nārada Purāṇa we do have a verse that prescribe 'sleeping near the Vişņu's idol' during an Ekādaśī fast.

> ##### [Chapter 23](https://archive.org/details/dli.bengal.10689.12945/page/n333/mode/2up) - The Procedure of Ekādaśī Fast
>
> दशम्यां प्रातरुत्थाय दन्तधावनपूर्वकम् ।  स्नापयेद्विधिवद्विष्णुं
> पूजयेत्प्रयतेन्द्रियः ॥ २३-१२ ॥
>
> > 12. On the Dasami (tenth) day, the devotee should get up very early in the morning (and should take bath) after duly washing the teeth. With
> >     purity and control over the sense-organs, he should duly bathe Vişņu
> >     and worship him (according to the prescription of the Sastras).
>
> एकादश्यां निराहारो निगृहीतेन्द्रियो भवेत् ।
> **शयीत सन्निधौ विष्णोर्नारायणपरायणः** ॥ २३-१३ ॥
>
> > 13. On the Ekadasi day, one should go without food and put curbs on the sense-organs. **Devoted to Narayana, he should go to bed in the
> >     vicinity of Vişņu.**

So atleast during Ekādaśī Fast (preceding night), one may sleep in the same room as that of the idol.